# How to move a Li tag from the first li to the last li to make a slider loop continuously

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to make my slider loop to the first image without shooting back to the first image passing the others, but instead adding the first Li tag to the last Li tag when ever the next arrow is pressed so that it is always adding the previous Li tags with the images inside to the end. Also need it to work on the previous as well.

This is how far I've got so far:

Html:

```
<div class="slider corners">
        <ul>
            <li class="corners"><span class="corners"></span><img src="../images/slider/image_1.png" width="854" height="393" alt="Image" /></li>
            <li class="corners"><span class="corners"></span><img src="../images/slider/image_2.png" width="854" height="393" alt="Image" /></li>
            <li class="corners"><span class="corners"></span><img src="../images/slider/image_3.png" width="854" height="393" alt="Image" /></li>
        </ul>                                              
</div>
<div id="slider-nav">
    <button class="left_arrow" data-dir="prev"></button>
    <button class="right_arrow" data-dir="next"></button>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$(function() {
var sliderUL = $('div.slider').css('overflow', 'hidden').children('ul'),
    imgs = sliderUL.find('img'),
    imgWidth = imgs[0].width,
    imgsLen = imgs.length,
    current = 1, 
    totalImgsWidth = imgsLen * imgWidth; 

$('#slider-nav').show().find('button').on('click', function() {
    var direction = $(this).attr('data-dir'),
    loc = imgWidth;     

    if ( direction === 'next' ) {
            $('.slider li').first().insertAfter( '.slider li:last');
        }else if ( direction === 'prev' ) {
            $('.slider li:last').insertAfter('.slider ul');
        }

    transition(sliderUL, loc, direction);
}); 

function transition( container, loc, direction ) {
    var unit; // -= +=

    if ( direction && loc !== 0 ) {
        unit = ( direction === 'next' ) ? '-=' : '+=';
    }

    container.animate({
        'margin-left': unit ? (unit + loc) : loc
    });
}
```

});

I was wondering if it is anything obvious or if I have done this completely wrong.

Comment: I think that it involves cloning divs and dynamically adding them to the end of the row continuously. There are so many slider/carousels available out there that it's generally better to simply use and adapt one that is already out there. You can end up pulling your hair out with these things.

Comment: Hi Billy, 
Thanks for your reply, I was tempted to use one that was already made and produce my own through that but want to learn as much as possible by doing it completely from scratch. I understand so far that I need this code:
    if ( direction === 'next' ) {
            $('.slider li').first().insertAfter( '.slider li:last');
        }else if ( direction === 'prev' ) {
            $('.slider li:last').insertAfter('.slider ul');
        } 
However for some reason which im not aware of it doesn't work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

several things wrong with this:

```
$('.slider li:last').insertAfter('.slider ul');
```

will put the last li after the UL like this:

```
    <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    </ul>
    <li></li> <-- here!
```

obviously not what you want, use this instead:

```
$('.slider li:last').insertBefore('.slider ul li:first');
```

your html data-dir values may as well be += and -= instead, so you can cut out the whole unit thing which will make it easier.

Once you have moved the first or last li to the start/end you then need to resposition the ul back to margin-left: 0; otherwise it will b